# Powershell script not reading AD phone numbers

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to edit the formatting of a group of user's phone numbers in AD. Specifically, replacing '-' characters with ' '. However, I do not seem to be able to access the existing phone number, which I need to do to replace the characters. I understand the -OfficePhone flag under Set-ADUser sets the telephoneNumber attribute, which seems to be working and the telephoneNumber attribute is there with the expected value in Attribute Editor as well. However when I try to access `$user.telephoneNumber` it comes up blank.

Here is my code, commented with what works/what doesn't and some behaviors:

```
foreach ($user in $users) {
    # Works. Prints out various basic attributes of user
    Write-Output $user

    # Doesn't work. Prints blank
    Write-Output $user.telephoneNumber

    # Works
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user -OfficePhone '555555555'
}
```

Comment: Your `Get-ADUser` command that queries all users needs to have `-Properties TelephoneNumber` to make that property accessible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As AdminOfThings has stated, you need to make the property accessible. You do this by using the `-Properties` parameter on the `Get-ADUser` command. Here is an example:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity USER_NAME -Properties TelephoneNumber
```

If you wanted to get all the properties back, you can use:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity USER_NAME -Properties *
```